# Expanding Generic Constraints

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

Please see the code below. The Namespaces represent DLL segmentations rather than Namespaces in the same DLL

```
Public Interface ICoreTableCollection
End Interface

Public Interface ICoreTableInstance
End Interface

Namespace Address.Tier1
    Public MustInherit Class AddressCollection(Of T As AddressInstance)
         Implements ICoreTableCollection
    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class AddressInstance
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace PartnerAddress.Tier1
    Public MustInherit Class PartnerAddressCollection(Of T As PartnerAddressInstance)
         Implements ICoreTableCollection
    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class PartnerAddressInstance
        MustOverride Function Parent(Of T As {ICoreTableCollection, New}, S As {ICoreTableInstance, New})() As S
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace Address.Tier2
    Public Class AddressCollection(Of T As AddressInstance)
        Inherits Address.Tier1.AddressCollection(Of T)
    End Class

    Public Class AddressInstance
        Inherits Address.Tier1.AddressInstance
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace PartnerAddress.Tier2
Public Class PartnerAddressCollection(Of T As PartnerAddressInstance)
    Inherits Tier1.PartnerAddressCollection(Of T)
End Class

Public Class PartnerAddressInstance
    Inherits Tier1.PartnerAddressInstance

    Public Overrides Function Parent(Of T As {New, ICoreTableCollection}, S As {New, ICoreTableInstance})() As S

    End Function

    '*****************
    'This is what I want, but it's not allowed
    '*****************
    'Public Overrides Function Parent(Of T As {New, Address.Tier2.AddressCollection(Of S)}, S As {New, Address.Tier2.AddressInstance})() As S

    'End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Is there anyway to make expand the Parent function constraints in Tier2.PartnerAddress to make it look like this.

```
'*****************
'This is what I want, but it's not allowed
'*****************
Public Overrides Function Parent(Of T As {New, Address.Tier2.AddressCollection(Of S)}, S As {New, Address.Tier2.AddressInstance})() As S

End Function
```

rather than

```
Public Overrides Function Parent(Of T As {New, ICoreTableCollection}, S As {New, ICoreTableInstance})() As S

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem boils down to how overrides work. Consider the following example:

```
Public MustInherit Class AAA
  MustOverride Function ConvertToString(obj As MyObject) As String
End Class
Public Class BBB : Inherits AAA
  Public Overrides Function ConvertToString(obj As MyObject) As String 'this line
    Return String.Empty
  End Function
End Class
Public Class MyObject
End Class
Public Class MyInheritedObject : Inherits MyObject
End Class
```

Now where it says `this line`, notice that you cannot change `MyObject` to `MyInheritedObject`. Yours are generics/types, but the same principles apply. This is per OOP, so your class needs to have a method signature identical to the base.

You can, however, shadow a method and use any signature you want on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the generic constraints in your overridden class. What you can do is add generic types. As a simplified example, instead of

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Public Overridable Sub Something(Of T As ICoreTableCollection)()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SubClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    ' doesn't compile:
    'Public Overrides Sub Something(Of T As AddressCollection)()

    'End Sub
End Class
```

Use

```
Public Class BaseClass(Of T As ICoreTableCollection)
    Public Overridable Sub Something()

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SubClass(Of T As AddressCollection)
    Inherits BaseClass(Of T)
    Public Overrides Sub Something()

    End Sub
End Class
```

(these examples use the following class/interface)

```
Public Interface ICoreTableCollection
End Interface
Public MustInherit Class AddressCollection
    Implements ICoreTableCollection
End Class
```